# On the conclusion of Liouville's theorem for bounded harmonic functions.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded harmonic function. Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$. We suppose that we just proved that $$|Du(x_0)|\to 0\quad\text{for}\;r\to\infty.$$ Where $r$ is the radius of a ball of center $x_0$ in which holds an estimate.

> How do I conclude by Taylor's theorem that $u$ is constant in $U$?

Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, then it is path connected. Why we have for all $x_1, x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ $$u(x_1)-u(x_0)=du(x_1+\theta(x_1-x_0))?$$ for some $\theta\in (0,1)$

From this Can we conclude? Thanks!

Comment: $Du$ is harmonic as well, then take a sufficiently large ball around $x$ and you know that the value of $(Du)(x)$ is the average of the value on the large ball, which can be arbitrarily small, hence $Du=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have proved that $Du(x_{0})=0$ for any $x_{0}\in\Bbb{R}^{n}$ . That is $Du$ is identically $0$ .  Then by [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables) you have for any $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^{n}$,

$u(x)-u(y)=Du(c)\cdot (x-y)=0$ for some $c$  on the line joining $x$ and $y$. Thus $u(x)=u(y)\,,\forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}^{n}$ and hence $u$ is a constant.

To prove that $Du(x_{0})=0$ you pick a ball of radius $r$ around $x_{0}$ .

Then you have by the Derivative Estimate (See [L.C.Evans PDE](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exushijie/pdf/textbooks/pde-evans.pdf) page $29$ for a proof).  $$|Du(x_{0})|\leq \frac{C}{r^{n+1}}\cdot ||u||_{L^{1}}\leq \frac{C}{r^{n+1}}\cdot ||u||_{L^{\infty}}\cdot\alpha(n)\cdot r^{n}= \frac{K}{r}$$ .

where $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\Bbb{R^{n}}$ .

As this holds for all $r>0$, you have $Du(x_{0})=0$ .